# How to add foreign key value on controller create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple database where users can create a task. I would like the index page to show which users created which task
The relationship between task and user is 1 user to many tasks. The task has a user_id foreign key. Users can only create a task when they are logged in via Devise.

My create controller is as follows but I don't know how to record the foreign key for that task i.e. the user that created it.

```
def create
    @challenge = Challenge.new(challenge_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @challenge.save
        format.html { redirect_to users_path, notice: 'Challenge was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @challenge }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @challenge.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you show your method `challenge_params`

Comment: I think thats the problem. This was created by rails scaffold but I don't have this method- presumably this is the way to pass in the user_id but I don't know how to create a method to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you should this:

```
@challenge = Challenge.new(challenge_params.merge({user_id: current_user.id}))
```

Comment: OK. it worked. Thanks. I suppose the learning point is that the params that are passed are also part of the INSERT TO statement. Cheers