# How to add foreign key value on controller create in a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31480645/how-to-add-foreign-key-value-on-controller-create) but the answer involved using current_user. This question is a little bit different.
I have a simple database where users can create a category. Each category has many tasks. I would like the user to click on a category to see the tasks for that category. The relationship between user and category is 1 to many and the relationship between category and task is one to many as well.

The problem I am having is in the creation of the foreign key in the task so it can tell which category it belongs to. The task create occurs when a user clicks a category

My model is as follows

```
category.rb

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tasks
    belongs_to :users
end

task.rb

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :categories
end
```

The controller

```
 def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
        render :layout => false
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        render :layout => false
      end
    end
  end
```

I think the problem is what I use for task_params. Currently I have no method for this. How do I get the category foreign key inserted into task when a user creates a task?

Comment: Your `belongs_to` associations are wrong FYI and also you don't have `belongs_to :category` in `Task` model. And where does `entry_params` come from?

Comment: Pavan is right - you need to add belongs_to :category in your task. Then in the task creation you can pass the category either by setting @task.category, or by providing the id in the task_params.

Comment: OK I changed the code- my mistake. How would I pass the id in task_params? Could you show me the line?

Comment: Did my answer worked?

Answer (score 0):

First change your `belongs_to` associations to ***singular***.

```
belongs_to :user #in category.rb
belongs_to :category #in task.rb
```

Then in your `create` method, define a ***instance variable*** for `category` like below

`@category = Category.find(params[:category_id])` and change your `create` method like below

```
def create
  @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
  @task = Task.new(task_params)
  @task.category_id = @category.id
  respond_to do |format|
    if @task.save
      format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
      render :layout => false
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      render :layout => false
    end
  end
end
```

And make sure you have `:category_id` in `task_params` method.

***Update:***

You should also have a `task_params` method defined in your controller like below.

```
def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:id, :blobby, :challenge_id, :category_id)
end
```

Comment: Hi Pavan. When you say 'And make sure you have :category_id in task_params method' does that mean that in the task.rb I should have def task_params task_params= :category_id end?

Comment: @SebastianZeki No! In your `tasks_controller`, `task_params`, you should be having `:category_id`.

Comment: so task = Task.new(task_params) should be task = Task.new(:category_id) in the code above     Task should be @task but can only use sign once in this box

Comment: @SebastianZeki No man! Do you have `task_prams` method? If so please post it in the question and i will explain.

Comment: No I don't have a task_params method. I did say in the question that I didn't know how I should do this

Comment: @SebastianZeki Tell me what are your attributes in `Task` model?

Comment: id,  blobby:string, challenge_id

Comment: I get a ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error. Just to clarify, the category table has field 'id' rather than category_id but the task table has 'category_id" field as a foreign key. Is that reflected in the code above?

Comment: Appreciated. Could you answer the question